# Pushing assets that are not in git repo to heroku

Tags: git, heroku, github

I have a web applicaiton. In **public** folder there should be assets (built js/images/index.html).

I don't want to to store these assets in my git repo (so **public** is added to regulqr .gitingore), so I wan't copy it there and then deploy.

The question is how to implement this workflow correctly?

What I thought is to do (this will be done by some automatic script):

1. Remove **public** folder from .gitingore (so now assets can be
   added to git)
2. Commit this changes (new .gitingore and assets)
3. git push heroku -f
4. git reset --hard HEAD~1 (return to state before heroku deploy)

What can be wrong with such approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That approach is not a good idea. In fact, resetting your database will cause the local database history to diverge from Heroku history.

After the first deploy, subsequent deploy will fail because the push is not fast-forward. git will require you to pull the changes from Heroku (effectively merging the assets back again in your repo). Otherwise, you will need to `--force` every push, but that's not a good approach, it will increase the chance to override the remote repository by mistake.

My suggestion is that, if you don't want the assets in the repository, then move them away completely from Heroku. For instance, you can keep the folder ignored, and deploy the assets on Amazon S3 or a CDN. You will get the advantage of having assets outside your Heroku app and serve them via CDN.

Comment: CND is one of the scenarios, but anyway there is also index.html that contains links to compiled resources (with hashed names) wich is created every time with new assets (not a big deal to store it in git, but I thougt how to have ideal schema for storing in git only what Is referred to server code). Coun't find a satisfying anwer yet for all this questins.

Comment: BTW that is the problem push --force to heroku? I don't need this repo be in completly consistent sync with my development state (in terms of all commits). I'm not going to pull from it anytime.

Comment: As I said, using --force completely bypasses the git history check. `--force` should not be used as part of a standard workflow, it's too easy to completely override (therefore deploy a wrong version) by mistake. You should not use `--force` by default, it exists for a reason.